# How to make webworker-thread close once the work assigned to them is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-worker

I am new at web workers and cant grasp the idea of terminating a worker once it has completed the task.

```
var Thread = require('webworker-threads');
data = [some data];
data.map(function(item){
     var worker = new Thread.Worker(someFunction(item)); // how to terminate this worker once someFunction has been executed.
});
```

i tried calling self.close() in a callback but no help. How to determine when the webworker has executed the function and how to terminate/close it?

Comment: [close()](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads#close), its in the readme.

Comment: i know but i cant make the worker terminate my program keeps running. Where should i be calling the close() method?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, I've not used it ;p but I don't think it works like that where you kill the main process, idea is you have the main process running and the threads do the work and you manage them.. with the close method.

Comment: if you have not got the solution then please refer the terminating web-worker part  :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers
.close() method is used by webwokers to terminate them., without affecting the main thread which created that web-worker.